# Attacks of Opportunity & Potion Drinking

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Is there some way to prevent an opponent from receiving an attack of opportunity when you consume a potion in a threatened square?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Drunken Brute](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/archetypes/paizo---barbarian-archetypes/drunken-brute)<sup>PFD20SRD</sup> Barbarian's archetype provides the Raging Drunk class feature.

> **Raging Drunk (Ex)**
>   While raging, the drunken brute can drink a potion, or a tankard of ale or similar quantity of alcohol, as a move action that does not provoke attacks of opportunity. A potion has its normal effect, while an alcoholic drink allows the barbarian to maintain her rage that round without expending a round of rage for the day (instead of the alcohol’s normal effects). For each alcoholic drink consumed while raging, the barbarian is nauseated for 1 round when her rage expires, in addition the normal fatigue that follows a rage. Tireless rage does not negate this nauseated condition but the internal fortitude rage power does.
>   This ability replaces fast movement.

So you can dip one level in Barbarian and rage then drink when needed. However, it comes with a steep price.

---

A non-core way to accomplish the same thing (but without the drawbacks of raging) is the feat [Bottoms Up](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/open-design/general-feats/bottoms-up)<sup>PFD20SRD</sup>.

> **Bottoms Up**
>   *You have trained yourself to swallow liquids in one quick gulp.*
>   **Prerequisite:** BAB +1.
>   **Benefit:** You can drink a potion or any other small volume of liquid as a move action that does not provoke attacks of opportunity.
>   **Note:** The benefit of this feat does not include any actions needed to retrieve a potion from your inventory, only the action of consuming it.